# Codestar pipeline successful but none of my files are in my ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, aws-codepipeline, aws-codestar

I am new to AWS,
and am working on an Express app using codestar.

I've just spent a lot of time figuring out how codestar works.

For the past 12 hours I have encountered a 502 bad gateway error on my deployed site.
So after going through these forums and stackoverflow, i figured out that since my "npm start" is working well, the files are probably not deployed well.

After setting up SSH into the EC2 instance, this hypothesis turned out to be true. I got it to work after manually uploading the Zip file of my project into elastic beanstalk.

1- The pipeline deployment had to be working because the nodejs-logs show that settings in my package.json file is properly set

2-But, the files i found in the built ec2 instance is probably the original nodejs one, and were not over written at all.

3- it was not on autoscaling, if that matters

How can I configure the codestar/EB/EC2 such that the pipeline can work properly from github to the E.Beanstalk instance? Is there a known issue and solution for this?

Thanks!